# Filling in missing conditions to avoid "subscipt out of bounds" error in tables

Tags: r

I have two different groups of people. Some individuals were not able to complete all of the conditions. Hence, the dataset is incomplete.

When I try to aggregate all data, I am getting an error message for ID2, when creating the new variable. I want to avoid error messages like

> subscript out of bounds

```
#ID1
a1 <- rep(c(1:3),4)
b1 <- rep(c(1:4),3)
tb1 <- table(b1,a1)

#ID2
a2 <- rep(c(1:3),4)
b2 <- rep(c(1,3),6)
tb2 <- table(b2,a2)

new_var <-  tb2["2",1] [tb2["2",1]>-1]
```

The value of the missing conditions can be 0 or NA. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try `tb2["2",1]` on its own and look at `tb2` to see the reason it doesn't work.

Comment: @Frank First: tb2["2",1] on its own does not work neither. I tried that already. Second: It does not work because there is no line "2". My question is how can i use the same function to create new_var for both ID01 and ID02? Without getting an error message for ID02.

Comment: "The value can be 0 or NA" -- I don't think NA can happen here. A table contains counts and I can't think of a way for a count to be NA. Similarly, I can't see how it could be `<= -1`, so I don't see the point of your testing `> -1`... If you're just after new_var and not the whole table, use `sum(b2 == 2 & a2 == 1)`, unless of course you "tried that already".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need such a thing to work, before construct the tables, make a1 and b1, etc factors. This will force `table` to count all levels:

```
a2 <- rep(c(1:3),4)
b2 <- rep(c(1,3),6)
a2 <- factor(a2, levels=1:3)
b2 <- factor(b2, levels=1:3)

tb2 <- table(b2,a2)
```

What are the results?

```
tb2
   a2
b2  1 2 3
  1 2 2 2
  2 0 0 0
  3 2 2 2
```